# tool to scan similar images

Tags: graphics, imagemagick, image-processing

What tools might be available in Ubuntu to scan many image files and detect similar ones despite different sizes, formats, etc?

Support for batch mode/cli would be especially good. For example, so I could write a script to favor the higher resolution/color depth versions and delete others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graphically [Digikam](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/digikam) can do that.

[image: Digikam screenshot]

---

For the command line you can use [`findimagedupes`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/findimagedupes).

The simple command to find recursively and report similar images is `findimagedupes -R ~/Pictures`.

Comment: Thanks. My search in the repos also found me `findimagedupes` and `puzzle-diff`. Like Digikam, Google's `Picasa` also has a gui tool for spotting repeated images, and it can be persuaded to run under Linux (via `wine` or natively maybe?)

Comment: Picasa runs (barely) under wine.

Comment: Exactly the same algorithm as *findimagedupes* implemented in Python (with GraphicsMagick doing the heavy lifting) here: http://github.com/pts/pyfindimagedupes